# Bootstrapping Standard Errors of lm

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, statistics-bootstrap, standard-error

I am new to R and I could need some help.

I have obtained the standard error and the p-value of a lm regression of y ~ z. Now i would like to do a bootstrap and compare the results. All i could find so far is the following code for bootstrapping the R-squared value:

```
for(i in 1:B) {
   indices <- sample(1:N, N, replace = TRUE)
   bs.data <- data[indices,]
   bs.OLS <- lm(y~z, data = bs.data)
   stor.se[i] <- summary(bs.OLS)$r.squared
}
```

I can't figure out how to return the Standard Error of the coefficient of z instead of the R-squared though. Replacing the `$r.squared` from the last line of the loop with `$sd` won't do the trick. `$sd(z)` and similar things won't work as well.

Comment: try `coef(summary(bs.OLS))["z","Std. Error"]`

Comment: Don't see why this was downvoted.  Straightforward question; not reproducible, but simple enough that a reproducible example doesn't seem absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

##### A Normal Call For Coefficients

This is actually pretty straightforward to do in R using the `boot` function of the `boot` library. As an example below using some data available in R. First you need to load the library and set a random seed.

```
#### Load Library and Set Seed ####
library(boot)
set.seed(123)
```

Then you create a function which essentially returns the coefficients for a regression on a designated subset of data.

```
#### Function for Estimating Coefficients of Regression ####
boot.fn = function(data,index) {
  
  #### Return Coefficients Here ####
  return(
    coef(
      lm(
        Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
        data = data,
        subset = index
      )
    )
  )
  
}
```

Then you run the `boot` function on the `iris` data by running the `boot.fn` function we created a thousand times.

```
#### Get Bootstrapped Estimates ####
b <- boot(iris,
     boot.fn,
     1000)
```

Finally, we can compare this with a regression fit normally with `lm`.

```
#### Fit Normal Regression ####
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
s <- summary(fit)

#### Compare ####
b
s$coefficients
```

One can see the difference in standard errors from both calls.

```
> b

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = iris, statistic = boot.fn, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original       bias    std. error
t1*  6.5262226 0.0033810961   0.4412810
t2* -0.2233611 0.0002787718   0.1447402

> s$coefficients
              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  6.5262226  0.4788963 13.627631 6.469702e-28
Sepal.Width -0.2233611  0.1550809 -1.440287 1.518983e-01
```

On a side note, this gets you your estimates for the SE of the t-statistic on an OLS regression. I'm not sure why you needed the z-statistic in your case, but alas doing something similar in R will get you the same thing.